# ImplicitRegion with RegionPlot Example

Tags: plotting, regions

Using Mathematica 11.0.1.0 on a MacBook Pro (OSX 10.11.6) I tried this:

```
Clear[x, y, reg1]
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[
   Log[10, 1 + x^2 + y^2] <= 1 + Log[10, x + y], {x, y}];
RegionPlot[reg1]
```

But got only this output:

> RegionPlot[reg1]

But I did get the area.

```
Area[reg1]
```

Which gave the correct answer $49\pi$. Then I tried:

```
RegionPlot[
 Log[10, 1 + x^2 + y^2] <= 1 + Log[10, x + y], {x, -2, 12}, {y, -2, 
  12}]
```

And I did get the correct image:

[image]

Is the fact that `RegionPlot[reg1]` did not work a bug that should be reported, or have I made some sort of mistake?

Comment: `RegionPlot[region]` and `RegionPlot[inequality, vars...]` are not equivalent.  For instance, try `DiscretizeRegion[reg1]` and `DiscretizeRegion[reg1, Method -> "RegionPlot"]`. I think your (failed) `RegionPlot` uses the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS JUST AN EXTENDED COMMENT**

The region definition can be simplified to

```
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[
   1 + x^2 + y^2 <= 10 (x + y),
   {x, y}];

Area[reg2]

(*  49 π  *)

Show[
 RegionPlot[reg2],
 ContourPlot[
  Log10[1 + x^2 + y^2] == 1 + Log10[x + y],
  {x, -2, 12}, {y, -2, 12},
  ContourStyle -> Red,
  PlotPoints -> 50]]
```

[image]